# Is it possible to set different screen resolutions for users in Win7?

Tags: windows-7, resolution

I have a htpc connected to the TV at a 1920x1080 resolution. When I connect to it via vnc or remote desktop from my main computer (1680x1050), the window is too big. Is it possible to create a user on the HTPC with this resolution, and use that one for the connections?

Comment: VNC has a screen scaling option... Why not enable that?

Answer (score 1):

With RDP, you can specify the resolution in the program itself.
When you open RDP, click on the "Show Options" button, then navigate to the 'Display' tab.
Once there, you can set the resolution when you connect to the other computer.

This won't require a separate user account.
As for VNC, I don't use it myself so I don't know specifically, but this seems to be pretty simple and easy: https://pods.iplantcollaborative.org/wiki/display/atmman/Changing+Screen+Resolution+for+the+VNC+Viewer